# Python: Running a for loop with multiple inputs and sorting the results into different lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a bit of code that looks like this:

```
measure_list=[]
for file in file_list:
    with open(file,"r") as read_data:
        y=read_data.read()
        if "Part: ABCD" in y:
            for line in m:
                if "Measure X:" in line:
                    measure_list.append(line)
                elif "Measure Y:" in line:
                    measure_list.append(line)

final=''.join(measure_list).replace("Measure","\nMeasure")
print(final)
```

(This last part just helps organize the output)

So this part of the code opens a group of files and scans each one to see if it is "Part: ABCD", and if it is, it will pull the lines for "Measure X:" and "Measure Y:" and add them to the measure_list. My problem is that I have a lot of files and there will be multiple "Part: ABCD" files. And after joining the list with .join() the output will then look like:

```
Part: ABCD
Measure X: (Numbers)
Measure Y: (Numbers)
Measure X: (Numbers)
Measure Y: (Numbers)
Measure X: (Numbers)
Measure Y: (Numbers)
```

My question is if anybody knows a way to organize the output so that it looks like so:

```
Part: ABCD
Measure X: (Numbers)
Measure X: (Numbers)
Measure X: (Numbers)
Measure Y: (Numbers)
Measure Y: (Numbers)
Measure Y: (Numbers)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using the built-in `sort()` or `sorted()` functions before you output the list.

Comment: what is `m` here?

Comment: m is meant to be y, sorry that is a typo

Comment: Can you give us a short example of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `measure_list` seems like this:

```
['Measure X: 1000', 'Measure Y: 2000', 'Measure X: 100' , 'Measure Y: 900']
```

If that's right, you can simply sort this `measure_list`:

`measure_list.sort()`

Then you will have:

```
['Measure X: 100', 'Measure X: 1000', 'Measure Y: 2000', 'Measure Y: 900']
```

Comment: This works, but it throws the "Part: ABCD" down to the end of the list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use two lists?

```
if "Measure X:" in line:
    listx.append(line)
elif "Measure Y:" in line:
    listy.append(line)
```

Then simply

```
final = ''.join(listx + listy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make two arrays of outputs and sort the input into each using a for loop with an if statement inside. Then join the two outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have python up in front of me so there might be a slight syntax edit needed.  This should sort the list by the X and Y portion of the "Measure X:..."

```
sorted(measure_list,key=lambda item: item.split()[1][0])
```